# C# MongoDB driver search date time column only by time or date

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a field in my MongoDB collection called:

```
{
    "EventDate" : ISODate("1974-10-28T13:41:06.499Z")
}
```

I want to be able to search by date alone and by time alone. For example:

```
public class SearchParams
{
    public DateTime? FromDate;
    public DateTime? ToDate;
    public TimeSpan? FromTime;
    public TimeSpan? ToTime;
}

Collection.Find(item => item.EventDate.Date >= searchParams.FromDate.Value.Date &&
                        item.EventDate.Date <= searchParams.ToDate.Value.Date &&
                        item.EventDate.TimeOfDay >= searchParams.FromTime.Value &&
                        item.EventDate.TimeOfDay <= searchParams.ToTime.Value);
```

But this seems to be not possible since MongoDB driver does not support `item.EventDate.Date` nor `item.EventDate.TimeOfDay`

So, is it possible to have one DateTime field and search on it by date only or by time only?

Comment: When you say 'search by date alone' do you mean that searching for '1974-10-28' should or shouldn't return your sample data?

Comment: `Collection.Find(item => item.EventDate >= searchParams.FromDate.Value.Date)` likely solves `FromDate`. `item.EventDate < searchParams.FromDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1)` likely solves `ToDate`.

Comment: `TimeSpan` is a terrible datatype to use for a start time. `TimeSpan` is for storing a **duration** of time. Not a **point** in time. You should use `DateTime` or one of the https://nodatime.org/ time types.

Comment: @mjwills - To answer all of your questions: searching for '1974-10-28' should return the sample data since the date is valid, I know that `item => item.EventDate` solves the date issue, but what about the time? And if someone sets `FromTime to 4pm and `ToTime` to 11pm I would want to return all data that has the `EventDate` time between there hours regardless of the date.